# What is the Maximum size of the image to be stored as BLOB in sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite

I am storing image as BLOB in sqlite database. Can anyone please tell me the Maximum size for the image to be stored as BLOB in sqlite database .

Answer (score 11):

See the [limits of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000).

This is roughly equivalent to 1 Gb.

Comment: At the same link another useful info: _The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647_

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of data to store in BLOB can go up to 2.1 Gb in sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2020: **2.15GB**

> https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html
>
> current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647

Workarounds:

- Compress your file.
- Split your file by column.
- Split your file by rows.
- Use multiple blob fields.

Comment: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#partitioned-datasets-multiple-files